# How to set bootstrap nav to break to mobile on iPad portrait?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

How can I set a breakpoint so that the navigation breaks to mobile on iPad portrait (768px), and displays the sub-navigation the same on portrait iPad that it does on mobile devices? It is currently showing the sub-nav with the same border and background that it does on desktop.

**HTML:**

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="../images/logo.png"></a>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default profile-btn">Profile</button>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">ABOUT US <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">WHAT WE DO<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
            <li class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 image-column">
              <ul>

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="item active hidden-md-down">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/156x120" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a>
                    <h4 class="picture-sub">LINK</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item active">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/156x120" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a>
                    <h4 class="picture-sub">LINK</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item active">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/156x120" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a>
                    <h4 class="picture-sub">LINK</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">LINK</li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header spacer">LINK</li>
                <li><a href="#">Link & Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link & Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Longer link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Longer link title</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header spacer">LINK</li>
                <li><a href="#">Long link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Long link title</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">LINK</li>
                <li><a href="#">long link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">long link title</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header spacer">LINK</li>
                <li><a href="#">Really long link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Longer link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link title here</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header spacer">LINK</li>
                <li><a href="#">Long link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Long link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Long link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Long link title</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">OUR RESULTS <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">NEWS</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">LOCATIONS</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">CONTACT</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
 header {
  text-align: center;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
}
.navbar-brand{
  img{
    width: 160px;
  }
}
header .header-brand {
  color: #777;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

header .header-brand:focus,
header .header-brand:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5e5e5e;
}
.navbar-toggle{
  float: left;
}
.icon-bar{
  background-color: #000;
}
.navbar .btn.profile-btn,
.navbar .btn.profile-btn:hover,
.navbar .btn.profile-btn:focus {
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 750px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px){
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 967px) {
  .navbar-header {
    float: none;
  }
  .mega-dropdown-menu ul {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar .navbar-toggle {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .navbar-text {
    float: none;
    margin: 15px 0;
  }
  /* since 3.1.0 */
  .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    display: block!important;
  }
  .collapsing {
    overflow: hidden!important;
  }
}
```

**JSFIDDLE: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/bv1yhxco/)**

Comment: Use something like this in your css media query? @media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {...css code...}

Comment: @LarsMertens - The issue is that the navigation is currently breaking at 992px, when it shouldn't be going to mobile nav until 768px. I tried adding the breakpoint you suggested, but it's not having any effect.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: https://coderwall.com/p/wpjw4w/change-the-bootstrap-navbar-breakpoint

Comment: I started with that, but I think there's something in the bootstrap library that may be overriding it.

Comment: Then you need to review the rules about **css specificity**, that is the reason why it is overriding. 
Your library needs to be called before the style.css because in Cascade Style Sheet the last style will be applied plus the rule on specificity, so you should focus on that. Are you sure? You should check in the debug which style is applied
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=css+specificity